# understanding the execution flow of GNU make

Tags: make

I have a following `Makefile`:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: foo

foo: bar
        @true

bar: file.txt
        touch file.txt

file.txt:
        @echo 'Created file.txt'

run:
        @echo 'Target without dependency.'
$
```

When I execute `make`, then `touch file.txt` is always executed even when it already exists. Why is that so? I expected `bar` target not to run if dependency is met, i.e `file.txt` exists.
In addition, am I correct that `make` by default picks the first target of the `Makefile` which is named `all` in my example?

Comment: You should learn a little bit about PHONY targets: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make does not care what the commands are doing; it just passes them to the shell.

Second, since you're never creating any `bar` file, `file.txt` will *always* be newer than `bar`, the `bar: file.txt` rule will match, and the `touch file.txt` command will be run.

You should obviously touch or create `file.txt` in the rule which has `file.txt` as its target.

> In addition, am I correct that make by default picks the first target of the Makefile which is named all in my example?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Makefile` is not using any non-standard feature, so your question is not specific to GNU make.

- The first regular target in the makefile is **all**, wich makes it the so called default target.
- Since I assume that no file, called `"all"` exist in the filesystem and since the makefile does not create one, `all` can be seen as a pseudo target that will always considered out of date.
- `all` depends on `foo` that also is not created by the makefile and thus also always considered out of date.
- `foo` depends on `bar` and when `foo` is "created" (from the view of the makefile), the dummy command `true` is executed...but not a file named `foo`. So `foo` is also always considered out of date.
- `bar` depends on `file.txt` and when `bar` is "created" (from the view of the makefile), the command `touch file.txt` is executed. This makes `file.txt` more recent and if a file `bar` did exists, this would actively make `bar` out of date with repect to `file.txt`, since `bar` would no longer be younger than `file.txt`.
- The command to make `file.txt` recent is just an `echo` command, that does not have any effect on `file.txt` but since any `make` implementation assumes a special date **younger than any file** (without checking the actual presence or time stamp of the target file) after a command for a target has been run, this does not cause the `make` run to fail.

So your makefile does not make or remake `file.txt` in the rule for `file.txt`.

On the other side, your `makefile` makes `file.txt` actively out of date with repect to `bar` when `bar` is expected to be processd. Note that `bar` depends on`file.txt`.

I recommend you to start with simpler makefiles to get a feeling on how `make` works.